# What is the future of English as a lingua franca?

Tags: history

English may now be the world's lingua franca, but according to a [review of Nicholas Ostler's latest book in The Economist](http://www.economist.com/node/17730434) the future is uncertain:

> English is expanding as a
>   lingua-franca but not as a mother
>   tongue. More than 1 billion people
>   speak English worldwide but only about
>   330m of them as a first language, and
>   this population is not spreading. The
>   future of English is in the hands of
>   countries outside the core Anglophone
>   group. Will they always learn English?
>
> Mr Ostler suggests that two new
>   factors—modern nationalism and
>   technology—will check the spread of
>   English.
>
> ...
>
> English will fade as a lingua-franca,
>   Mr Ostler argues, but not because some
>   other language will take its place. No
>   pretender is pan-regional enough, and
>   only Africa’s linguistic situation may
>   be sufficiently fluid to have its
>   future choices influenced by
>   outsiders. Rather, English will have
>   no successor because none will be
>   needed. Technology, Mr Ostler
>   believes, will fill the need.
>
> This argument relies on huge advances
>   in computer translation and speech
>   recognition. Mr Ostler acknowledges
>   that so far such software is a
>   disappointment even after 50 years of
>   intense research, and an explosion in
>   the power of computers. But half a
>   century, though aeons in computer
>   time, is an instant in the sweep of
>   language history.

What do you think? Are the days of English as a global second language numbered?

Comment: Mr Ostler would be well advised to [check Jeff Atwood's blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/06/whatever-happened-to-voice-recognition.html) or head straight to [Rest in Peas: The Unrecognized Death of Speech Recognition](http://robertfortner.posterous.com/the-unrecognized-death-of-speech-recognition).

Comment: This question seems overly broad and subjective for a Q&A forum. It might be better asked on a discussion forum.

Answer (score 3):

Translation has gotten vastly better than it used to, but it will never replace human language comprehension because of the same reason that human translators can't replace human language comprehension - people rarely express themselves in a clear, unambiguous way, except for trivial concepts.

The problem is more fundamental than learning to express oneself more precisely - people often possess their thought precisely, and only through the interchange of context and conversation is it made clear. Computer translation will help, but as long as there is human communication, there will be a language barrier. A dialect barrier, even. So there will be a lingua franca.

Will it be English? The lingua franca is a function of economic power...non-linguists  learn a foreign language because it is generally in their economic interest somehow. If English-speaking countries continue to predominate economically, then English will be the lingua franca. The show Firefly proposed that in the future, the lingua franca would be English sprinkled with Chinese phrases...not quite a pidgin, but definitely with a strong Chinese influence.

A useful predictor might be the total non-distinct number of pages published in a given language. If those patterns change, that might predict the rise of another lingua franca.